# Oracle Sql Developer Can't start

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I tried to start Sql developer but it doesn't show anything and I tried to start it in cmd it shows this error:

**C:\Windows\system32>C:\app\JUSTICENTOI\product\12.1.0\dbhome_2\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper
_execv() failed, err=2can't open C:\app\JUSTICENTOI\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\jdk\jre\lib\tzmappings.**

how can I solve this error?

Comment: Doe the file 'C:\app\JUSTICENTOI\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\jdk\jre\lib\tzmappings" exist?  If so, what are the permissions on it and all of it's parent directories?

Comment: pull down sqldev 20.4 from oracle.com/sqldeveloper - get the big file for windows, includes the JDK. unzip to a new directory, run the EXE from the top directory

Comment: The is no tzmappings in lib directory. I'll download sqldev 20.4